# javascript XSLT nodes, selecting the first of a group (merge-like)

Tags: xslt, grouping, nodes

after reading some of the merge posts out here, my question appears to be simpler and I am not capable to find out the answer. So I post a new question.

The original xml

```
<data>

<proteins>
<protein>
<accession>111</accession>
</protein>
</proteins>

<peptides>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>AAA</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>AAA</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>AAA</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
</peptides>

</data>
```

the xslt, used as an .xsl page to be interpreted by a browser

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates select="/data/proteins/protein" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data/proteins/protein">
<xsl:apply-templates select="/data/peptides/peptide[accession = current()/accession]" >
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide">
...
</xsl:template>
```

the output that I got (conceptually, since this is a simplification of a larger code)

```
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>AAA</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>AAA</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>AAA</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
```

and the output that I would like to have, i.e. to have only one entry for each sequence, so to avoid having redudancy

```
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>AAA</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
<accession>111</accession>
<sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
```

I would be happy to have just the first of the nodes that share the same sequence (so not merging them). 
Any help is highly welcomed :)

Thanks!

Comment: `/data/peptides/peptide[accession = current()/accession]` is not a valid XPath expression.  Please fix your source code and clarify your question.

Comment: could you point me to some doc where it explains why is not a valid XPath expression? honestly I do not know. Regarding the clarification of the question, original xml and desired xml is posted, the other information might be superfluous, but what information is lacking?

Comment: @PointedEars - Why do you think that?

Comment: Ask any XPath processor, like with `document.evaluate("/data/peptides/peptide[accession = current()/accession]", document, null, 0, null)` in your (non-MSHTML-based) browser's script console. Read the [XPath 1.0 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/); the part between the `[`…`]` cannot be produced with *PredicateExpr*. Your XSLT processor (which one?) should be able display an error message as well.

Comment: Further, your question is unclear as to the output you expect; your later statement somehow modifies the posted expected output, but it is ambiguous ("the first of the nodes").

Comment: @PointedEars: The XPath expression you are referring to is *correct* when used within an XSLT transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your stylesheet is missing is a way to identify the first in a group of identical items. The following stylesheet uses an `xsl:key` to group `peptide` elements by a combination of their `accession` and `sequence` values:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="peptide" 
                             use="concat(accession, '|', sequence)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root><xsl:apply-templates select="/*/proteins/protein"/></root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="protein">
        <xsl:apply-templates
            select="../../peptides/peptide[accession=current()/accession]"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="peptide[generate-id()=
             generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence))[1])]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="peptide"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<root>
    <peptide>
        <accession>111</accession>
        <sequence>AAA</sequence>
    </peptide>
    <peptide>
        <accession>111</accession>
        <sequence>BBB</sequence>
    </peptide>
</root>
```

**Explanation:** The following line:

```
<xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="peptide" 
                         use="concat(., accession, sequence)"/>
```

...groups `peptide` elements using keys whose values are equal to `concat(., accession, sequence)`. Elements can be later retrieved by reproducing the key for some `peptide` element:

```
key('byAccSeq', concat(/path/to/peptide, accession, sequence))
```

To match the first element in the list of nodes returned for some key, we use the following template/pattern:

```
<xsl:template match="peptide[generate-id()=
               generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(., accession, sequence))[1])]">
```

The `generate-id` function returns a unique identifier for every node in the document. We're asking for any `peptide` element whose unique ID is equal to the unique ID of a node that's first in the list for some key.

We then ignore all other `peptide` elements -- the ones that aren't first for some key -- with the following template:

```
<xsl:template match="peptide"/>
```

This grouping technique is called the Muenchian Method. Further reading:

- http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: I still do not see how `../../peptides/peptide[accession=current()/accession]` can be a valid XPath expression, but it is possible that this is XSLT-specific. If so, please explain.

Comment: Which part is bothering you? Is it `current()`? That's an XSLT function that returns a node-set containing only the node that the template is currently processing. See here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-current

Comment: We're selecting all `peptide` elements having a child element named `accession` whose value is equal to that of the current node's `accession` element.

Comment: Thank you, I understand now. Besides not having needed `current()` yet, I did not see `accession` being equivalent to `accession/text()`, which it must be in an *EqualityExpr*.

Comment: @PointedEars - These two quotes from the spec should explain: 1) "If both objects to be compared are node-sets, then the comparison will be true if and only if there is a node in the first node-set and a node in the second node-set such that the result of performing the comparison on the string-values of the two nodes is true." 2) "The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order."

Comment: @lwburk: Just a minor remark: When concatenating values to form the key, it is safe to add a delimiter (a string that is guaranteed not to be part of either the end of a value or of the beginning of a value). Otherwise there can be problems, such as `"profile1"` which can be both the result of `concat('pro', 'file1')` or `concat('profile', 1)`. If both combinations are present in the XML file, they will incorrectly be grouped together.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - Quite right. I had another typo, too. Both fixed.

Comment: @PointedEars - Yes, but the spec is definitive.

Comment: Thanks a lot, a while to see why this approach was not working on my case. Now I've find out why. I don't know why (perhaps I should change it, probably I am worried about having other nodes with the same name in the xml file) but I prefer not to use relative pathways. Thus, everything works ok if I use absolute paths except for the last line,  using `<xsl:template match="peptide"/>`is ok, using `<xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide"/>` fails. Why??
**EDIT: surprisingly, writting the line BEFORE the other template, works again. I really do not understand why ...

Answer (score 1):

**An alternate [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html)** (just one template and a single instruction):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kPepByAccAndSeq" match="peptide"
  use="concat(accession, '+', sequence)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy-of select=
    "/*/peptides
          /peptide
              [generate-id()
              =
               generate-id(key('kPepByAccAndSeq',
                               concat(accession, '+', sequence)
                              )[1]
                          )
              ]
    "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied to the provided XML document**:

```
<data>
    <proteins>
        <protein>
            <accession>111</accession>
        </protein>
    </proteins>
    <peptides>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>AAA</sequence>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>AAA</sequence>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>AAA</sequence>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
        </peptide>
        <peptide>
            <accession>111</accession>
            <sequence>BBB</sequence>
        </peptide>
    </peptides>
</data>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<peptide>
   <accession>111</accession>
   <sequence>AAA</sequence>
</peptide>
<peptide>
   <accession>111</accession>
   <sequence>BBB</sequence>
</peptide>
```

**Explanation**: Muenchian grouping where the key value is a combination of the values of two elements.

Comment: In this case, I need to group all peptides belonging to one accession, and within all peptides group them by sequence and show only one of this group. With your solution I could not do the first filtration as far as I can see. But this makes me think that I could group peptides by accession and by accession and sequence, and do a for-each for both groups. I cannot see if this would be more efficient than doing the apply-template call, but if it was the case I would move to this solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Gerard: This solution produces exactly the result that is shown as wanted in your question. Now in your comment you come up with new requirements I am seeing for the first time. Please, understand that your question in its present form is completely answered -- has two correct answers, mine being shorter and simpler. At this point you have two choices: accept the answer you feel is best, and post a new SO question stating your new requirements. Or, you could edit your current question with the new requirements. Of these two possible choices I'd strongly recommend going up with the first one.

Comment: Got it, I do not see any button with an "accept", so I understand that it ends here. I will follow your suggestion, thanks :)