# xslt dynamic / conditional apply-template in function of a variable?

Tags: xslt, dynamic, conditional-statements, apply-templates

I want to display two different XSLT transformations in function of what the user want. The entire XSL file is the same, except for one line.

This line should be as it

```
<xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()=generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(protein_accessions/accession, '|', sequence))[1])]">
```

or as it

```
<xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide">
```

My first idea was to create two different .xsl files, and to apply them (javascript) in function of a variable value.

```
var xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xslDoc);
xhtml = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc,document);
```

However, it is just a line and I would like to maintain only one file. I would like to do something like this

```
<xsl:param name="variable"/>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$variable = 0">
<xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()=generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(protein_accessions/accession, '|', sequence))[1])]">
...
</xsl:template>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide">
...
</xsl:template>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

But it does not work.

trying with the feature "mode" in the xsl:apply-templates, this code neither works

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="/data/peptides/peptide" use="concat(accession, '|', sequence)"/>

<xsl:param name="analysis" select="1"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<root><name><xsl:value-of select="$analysis"/></name><xsl:apply-templates select="/data/proteins/protein"/></root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data/proteins/protein">
<xsl:apply-templates select="/data/peptides/peptide[accession=current()/accession]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$analysis=1">
<xsl:apply-templates select="/data/peptides/peptide" mode="one"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:apply-templates select="/data/peptides/peptide[accession=current()/accession]" mode="two"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

<xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide" mode="one">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()=
           generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence))[1])]" mode="two">
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

-> http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/sgWUFu/2

- this code is not correct since xsl:choose cannot be a child of xsl:stylesheet

SOLVED (improved below), this is the code that makes what I wanted

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="/data/peptides/peptide" use="concat(accession, '|', sequence)"/>
    <xsl:param name="analysis" select="1"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="$analysis"/>
            </name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/proteins/protein"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/data/proteins/protein">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$analysis=1">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/peptides/peptide[accession=current()/accession]" mode="one"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/peptides/peptide[accession=current()/accession]" mode="two"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide" mode="one">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide" mode="two"/>

    <xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()=
    generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence)))]" mode="two">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

IMPROVED: the final code is much easier to read with much less duplicated code
[here](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/sgWUFu/6)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="analysis" select="0"/>
    <xsl:key name="byAcc"    match="/data/peptides/peptide" use="accession" />
    <xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="/data/peptides/peptide" use="concat(accession, '|', sequence)"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="$analysis"/>
            </name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="/data/proteins/protein" />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/data/proteins/protein">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$analysis=1">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('byAcc',accession)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="key('byAcc',accession)[
                generate-id()
                =
                generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence)))]" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/data/peptides/peptide">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I keep the apply-template calls because I need it, but without them (as in the original code, see comments) is even simpler.

Thanks again, not only for answering but for teaching XSLT :)

Comment: Have a look at the improved version of your solution: http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/sgWUFu/5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/data/peptides/peptide[
  generate-id()
  =
  generate-id(
    key('byAccSeq', concat(protein_accessions/accession, '|', sequence))[1]
  )
]
```

and

```
/data/peptides/peptide[
  generate-id()
  =
  generate-id(
    key('byAccSeq', concat(protein_accessions/accession, '|', sequence))
  )
]
```

are equivalent. `generate-id()` always returns the ID of the first node in the node-set that has been passed to it.

Therefore it does not make any difference whether you use `generate-id(some-node-set)` or `generate-id(some-node-set[1])`. You can use either one of the XSLT files.

Comment: you are right, but in the past I was able to get not the first but all the nodes, so that I got a difference ([link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466734/javascript-xslt-nodes-selecting-the-first-of-a-group-merge-like/8468098#8468098)), then now I need to recover that expression

Comment: @Gerard: I'm not sure what you are doing there. Your "mode 1" and "mode 2" templates are doing the exact same thing (which is, a `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>`). What's the point in having two equal templates? Also, `<xsl:choose>` cannot be the child of `<xsl:stylesheet>`, so from my point of view, this code is not even syntactically correct.

Comment: Obviously this is a simplification of a larger script. You're right that the code is not syntactically correct, I was hoping to some alternative. Although not syntactically correct, I believe that what I would like to do can be understood with the code that I provide.

Comment: @Gerard Providing code that does not even work is not helpful *at all*. How am I supposed to help you if your samples don't even compile? Should I guess my way through your code until I uncover a problem that might be what you mean? Seriously. Provide working code that exposes the exact problem you have a question about. I'm helping you for free, it's the very least you can do.

Comment: I understand the frustration, but I had 2 options
a) put just the conceptual problem, i.e. what I would like to do, but without knowing how,
b) the same, but providing some useless code, just to make easier to understand what I'd like to do. 
I have tried b), also thinking that the code was correct (you are the one that have told me it wasn't incorrect). But actually, thanks to you and to Siva Charan, I know have the code I wanted so the problem is solved. I have posted the final code in the question. Also I know the help is for free, and I am really grateful for this :)

Comment: @Gerard I am pretty sure your code is a lot more complicated that it has to be. And regarding option **b)** - it would still be your task to create a minimal code sample that *compiles* and *shows your problem*. And yes, this sometimes involves writing an entirely new piece of code, if copying from your existing code would make it "useless".

Comment: the simplified code was already posted in the question [here](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/sgWUFu/2). I insist, since it didn't throw any parser error, I didn't notice it was syntactically incorrect. Once I've known, and together with the final solution, this has been posted in the original question. I have not erased the bad code since it can be useful for future readers. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Tomalak: You are right. After seeing Gerard solution, I thought of changing his provided solution in a proper form. Finally came up with proper shortest representation of **XSLT code** for his solution.

Comment: @Gerard FYI based on your code I've created [a simpler version](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/sgWUFu/5). No template modes, no code duplication, no complex match expressions.

Comment: @Tomalak, this is it, much easier to read (at least for me) and much cleaner. Thanks again. I've included in my script and works like a charm :)

Comment: @Gerard Good to hear. I hope your next XSLT question comes with working samples from the start. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: Congrats on getting the gold XSLT badge.

Comment: @Dimitre Thank you! Still a very lonely badge to have, I'm afraid.

Comment: @Tomalak: It was *me* who felt very lonely with this badge for two years :)

Comment: @Dimitre Well, then you've got company now. Let's see how long it takes for the third one to arrive.

Comment: @Tomalak: In one year Michael Kay will be here -- ahead of anyone else.

Comment: @Dimitre Probably that's the next one, correct. Unless he looses interest in SO, that is.

Answer (score 1):

Change from `<xsl:template>` to `<xsl:apply-templates>`

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()=generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(protein_accessions/accession, '|', sequence))[1])]" mode="type1" />

<xsl:apply-templates select="/data/peptides/peptide[generate-id()=generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(protein_accessions/accession, '|', sequence)))]" mode="type2" />
```

After that, write `<xsl:template>` for both or in one accordingly.

## Modify your solution in shorter way:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="byAccSeq" match="/data/peptides/peptide" use="concat(accession, '|', sequence)"/>
    <xsl:param name="analysis" select="2"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <name>
                <xsl:value-of select="$analysis"/>
            </name>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="data[peptides/peptide/accession=proteins/protein/accession]/peptides" />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="peptides">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$analysis=1">
                <xsl:copy-of select="peptide"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:for-each select="peptide[generate-id()=generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence)))]">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I have tested my code as per your input XML & output. Now I can replicate the same.

On my code, still I can reduce some more lines of code

Replace `<xsl:for-each>` with below line:-

```
<xsl:copy-of select="peptide[generate-id()=generate-id(key('byAccSeq', concat(accession, '|', sequence)))]"/>
```

Check it out..

Comment: I am trying as you suggest, without success. The [code](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/sgWUFu/2)

Comment: @Gerard: I have update my answer, with a proper XSLT code (based on your code). Now I can replicate the same output, as per your input XML. Check and let me know.

Comment: thanks a lot. Since I need to keep the apply-template calls, I think the for-each solution wouldn't work. Instead, using two groups of nodes with "Key" and call the templates using them is like the easiest way I can think of doing it.

Comment: No, it will work. My suggestion for testing **XSLT** codes, better use **XML SPY**. Tomalak solution is also good one.

Comment: @Gerard: You are still using repetitive xpath and `<xsl:apply-templates>` on your code for matching and printing.

Comment: regarding the for-each solution, now I see I could skip the apply-templates. However, where I put the `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` I need to put xhtml code, for example [here](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/sgWUFu/7). With the foreach loop, if I'm not wrong I should put 2 times this code. Then, with this explanation, am I still using repetitive commands? I am very interested in correcting this.